# How to record audio and save in internal storage in fragment - android studio

Tags: xml, kotlin, fragment

I'm using android studio kotlin and want to record audio and save it in internal storage in fragment page. But this error always appear

Error:

`com.fypvpreventor.VpreventorFYP, PID: 23176`
`java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.`
`at android.media.MediaRecorder.native_setAudioSource(Native Method)`
`at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.java:1923)`
`at com.fypvpreventor.VpreventorFYP.fragments.SensorFragment.onViewCreated(SensorFragment.kt:89)`
`at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)`
`at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)`
`at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)`
`at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)`
`at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)`
`at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)`
`at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)`
`at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)`
`at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)`
`at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)`
`at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668)`
`at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)`
`at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)`
`at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)`

Answer (score 0):

Open your AndroidManifest.xml file and then add the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: already added, but still...

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Destroyer King,

Please try the following solution.

Add Below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Add ask runtime permission in your code for record audio and write external storage

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO },
                10);
    } else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                11);
    }
    else {
        Write your coder here for record audio
    }
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 10 && requestCode == 11)
    {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        { recordAudio();
        }
        else
        { //User denied Permission.
        }
    }
}
```

Hope This Helps!